# How to get switch MAC address if it's a layer2 one?

Tags: networking, mac-address

```
arp -a
```

doesn't show it. How can I get the MAC of it then? (on ex.: from a Linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your switch is a managed switch, then you can use `lldpctl` from the `lldpd` package (on Debian/Ubuntu) to know its MAC address.

The `lldp` package is described as follows:

> lldpd is a 802.1ab implementation (LLDP) to help you locate neighbors of all your equipments.

The man page for `lldpctl` shows how to use it:

```
NAME
     lldpctl — control LLDP daemon

SYNOPSIS
     lldpctl [-d] [-L location] [-P policy] [-O poe] [-o poe] [interface ...]

DESCRIPTION
     The lldpctl program controls lldpd(8) daemon.

     When no specific option is given, lldpctl displays the list of 
     discovered neighbors along with some of their advertised capabilities.
     If some interfaces are given, only those interfaces will be displayed.
...
```

#### References

- [lldp website](http://vincentbernat.github.io/lldpd/)
- [Additional packages for other distros](http://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home%3avbernat&package=lldpd)

Comment: what about `nmap` ?

Comment: How `nmap` works to determine Switch?

Comment: I thought, he just need mac address.

Comment: But he doesn't know the IP of Switch.

Comment: This is when you're trying to determine which port on your computer is connected to which port on the switch.

Comment: Can you post some example ? because I've configure to just see that but facing some issue.. http://paste.ubuntu.com/6036813/